# Received 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import' when executing Karma and Jasmine Test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have this Angular Node app and I am in the process of trying to get Jasmine and Karma set up.

However, when I try to run a simple test, I am receiving this error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

at specs/boxService.spec.js:2

**boxService.spec.js**

```
import { BoxService } from './services/boxService.js';

describe("BoxService", function() {
  var service;
  beforeEach(function(){
    service = new BoxService
  });

  describe('getAllItemsInRootFolder', function() {
    it('returns an object representing all the files in Box', function() {
      let callBack = function(err, data) {
        if(err) throw err;
        expect(data).toNotBe(null)
      }
      service.getAllItemsInRootFolder(callBack)
    });
  });
```

**boxService.js**

```
export class BoxService{

  var developerToken = 'IdSqAIHSUCkD7J67hVsVR1FjWtkrODre'

  getAllItemsInRootFolder(callBack){
    client.folders.getItems( '0', {
            fields: 'name,modified_at,size,url,permissions,sync_state',
            offset: 0,
            limit: 25 }, callBack
    );
  }
```

I am scratching my head why!!! please help

Comment: import is part of Es6. Are you using a transpiler or something that accepts Es6 and gives you Es5 code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by adding Babel as the pre processor!!

package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.23.0",
    "box-node-sdk": "^1.3.0",
    "ejs": "2.4.1",
    "express": "4.13.3"
  },
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```